# D3.zoom jumps when using mouse wheel after programmatically zoom

Tags: d3.js, svg, zooming

When I zoom to a specific location on a mouse click and then try to pan or when I'm using the mouse wheel, the zoom behavior jumps. It seems that my zoom level is being restored like it was before the mouse click.

Here is my event handler:

```
function click(d) {
    var x, y, k;

    if (d && centered !== d) {
       var centroid = path.centroid(d);
       x = centroid[0];
       y = centroid[1];
       k = 4;
       centered = d;
     } else {
       x = width / 2;
       y = height / 2;
       k = 1;
       centered = null;
    }


    svgContainer.transition()
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")");
}
```

And this is how I "activate" my zoom and pan functionalities.

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
         svgContainer.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    }))
    .append("g")
    ...

svgContainer.selectAll(null)
    .data(feat.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .on("click", click)
     ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Background**

You are manipulating the transform applied to your elements in the click function but not updating the zoom state to reflect this. d3.zoom does not track an element's transform at all. So when you modify the transform attribute of an element independently of d3.zoom, d3.zoom no longer "knows" what the transform is of that element - it remains unchanged. D3.zoom does track zoom state - internally and independently of any element's transform attribute.

It might seem odd that d3.zoom doesn't track an element's transform, but there is good reason. d3.zoom isn't always used to manipulate the transform of an element, it may alter something like element width or a scale while that element's transform remains unchanged. Here's a [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/6edf5fea96a6987ee53b8683c42aa50b) of mine where d3.zoom here manipulates only the radius of circles on canvas.

**Problem**

As you don't update the zoom state in your click event, d3.zoom picks up where it was last left when applying a new zoom event, which explains your symptom: "It seems that my zoom level being restored like it was before the mouse click."

**Solution**

So, what do you need to do? You need to pass your zoom transform to d3.zoom and trigger a zoom event. This way d3.zoom is apprised of the current zoom state. Luckily there is a method for this. We take a d3.zoomIdentity (k=1,x=0,y=0) and translate and scale as appropriate, we can translate, scale, and then translate again as you have done too:

```
   // Create a zoom transform from d3.zoomIdentity
   var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(250,150)
    .scale(k)
    .translate(-x,-y);
```

And then we apply the zoom by calling zoom.transform which according to the docs:

> sets the current zoom transform of the selected elements to the
>   specified transform, instantaneously emitting start, zoom and end
>   events. If selection is a transition, defines a “zoom” tween to the
>   specified transform using d3.interpolateZoom, emitting a start event
>   when the transition starts, zoom events for each tick of the
>   transition, and then an end event when the transition ends (or is
>   interrupted). ([link](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_transform))

We can call zoom.transform with:

```
   // Apply the zoom and trigger a zoom event with a provided zoom transform:
   svg.call(zoom.transform, transform);
```

So if this is analagous to what you have:

```js
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1,8])
  .translateExtent([[0,0],[500,300]])
  .on("zoom",zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("div")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",300)
  .call(zoom);
  
var g = svg.append("g");
  
var rects = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(750))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width",17)
  .attr("height",17)
  .attr("fill","#eee")
  .attr("y", function(d) { return Math.floor(d/50) * 20; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d%50 * 20; })
  .on("click", click);

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

function click(d) {
   rects.attr("fill","#eee");  
   
   var clicked = d3.select(this);
   clicked.attr("fill","orange");
   
   var x = +clicked.attr("x")+10;
   var y = +clicked.attr("y")+10;
   var k = 5;
   
   var transform = "translate(" + 250 + "," + 150 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")";
   
   g.transition()
     .attr("transform",transform)
     .duration(1000);
}
```

```css
rect {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
```

This can be analagous to your solution:

```js
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1,8])
  .translateExtent([[0,0],[500,300]])
  .on("zoom",zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("div")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",300)
  .call(zoom);
  
var g = svg.append("g");
  
var rects = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(750))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width",17)
  .attr("height",17)
  .attr("fill","#eee")
  .attr("y", function(d) { return Math.floor(d/50) * 20; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d%50 * 20; })
  .on("click", click);

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

function click(d) {
   rects.attr("fill","#eee");  
   
   var clicked = d3.select(this);
   clicked.attr("fill","orange");
   
   var x = +clicked.attr("x")+10;
   var y = +clicked.attr("y")+10;
   var k = 5;

   // Create a zoom transform from d3.zoomIdentity
   var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(250,150)
    .scale(k)
    .translate(-x,-y);
   
   // Apply the zoom and trigger a zoom event:
   svg.call(zoom.transform, transform);

}
```

```css
rect {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation but it still jumps. I did exactly what you suggested to me. https://jsfiddle.net/wx9r261v/1/

Comment: Will take a look shortly

Comment: If you click to zoom and then pan, does it reset? The jumpiness could just be the severity of the change in zoom level without a transition, does the problem remain if you apply a transition in the zoom function: `d3.select("#mainGroup").transition().attr("transform", d3.event.transform);`?

Comment: Yes it does reset on pan. When I add transition then the zoom and pan behavior gets even worse. I did create a new fiddle where you can see this effect: https://jsfiddle.net/3gf54qL8/

Comment: Ah, you are calling the zoom on two different things, the `svg` and the child `g`, `svgContainer` holds a `g`, try: `d3.select("#svg-id").call(zoom.transform,transform)`. It is why I use two selections above, one for the `g`, one for the `svg` - the `g` only has mouse interaction where elements are, the svg everywhere, so I call the zoom on the svg, apply it to the g. Thanks for updating the fiddle, here's updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9kbc13u/) with that change.

Comment: Hi  @AndrewReid. Your D3 responses in general are very well communicated. Thank you. In relation to your posts above you stated " D3.zoom does track zoom state". In the docs it states "The zoom behavior stores the zoom state on the element to which the zoom behavior was applied, not on the zoom behavior itself." May you please explain the the difference between your statement and the docs, as this has confused me.

Comment: Yeah, I see why that might be confusing - Much of the zoom behavior (event listeners and state) is essentially stored on the DOM element itself. But it does so in custom properties on a DOM element (look at `__zoom` and `__on` properties of a DOM element that has had a zoom called on it). The difference between the docs and my answer is that I am simply considering the properties that d3-zoom adds to a DOM element as part of the zoom behavior, whereas, the docs consider these to be separate. My approach certainly makes the answer simpler, but I could add some extra clarification.

Comment: @AndrewReid Tbh, your answer led me to watch the event throughout the lifecycle of my chart and made me realize that the event still had the previous translations applied. So it absolutely answered the question. I do think the d3-zoom documentation could do with a little extra to make it clear that in fact the event does persist the transformations. I will post on GitHub to suggest it is added in and see if there is any desire to update.