# D3JS v5 Zoom - The transform value changes between zoom on button and mouse wheel

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a project using D3js V5 that takes the input of a CSV file and returns a Workflow diagram, everything is working fine besides on it's own.
My problem is when I fit the workflow, through a Fit Button, and after that I use the mouse wheel to zoom in or out it just jumps to the previous zoom and position settings.

After some research I've found that after D3v4+ that "Zoom behaviours no longer store the active zoom transform (i.e., the visible region; the scale and translate) internally. The zoom transform is now stored on any elements to which the zoom behaviour has been applied.([link](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#zooming-d3-zoom))"

That being said I cannot make it work and that's why I'm asking for your help.

The code is has follows:

```
document.getElementById('fitBTN').addEventListener('click', zoomFit);

function zoomFit() {
    let bounds = document.getElementById('svgContent').getBBox();
    let parent = document.getElementById('svgContent').parentElement;
    let fullWidth = parent.clientWidth,
        fullHeight = parent.clientHeight;
    let width = bounds.width,
        height = bounds.height;
    let midX = bounds.x + width / 2,
        midY = bounds.y + height / 2;
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) return; // nothing to fit
    let scale = 0.95 / Math.max(width / fullWidth, height / fullHeight);
    let translate = [
        fullWidth / 2 - scale * midX,
        fullHeight / 2 - scale * midY
    ];

    document
        .getElementById('svgContent')
        .setAttribute(
            'transform',
            'translate(' +
                translate[0] +
                ',' +
                translate[1] +
                ') scale(' +
                scale +
                ')'
        );
}

svg
    .call(
        zoom()
            .on('zoom', () => {
                document
                    .getElementById('svgContent')
                    .setAttribute(
                        'transform',
                        'translate(' +
                            currentEvent.transform.x * 0.125 +
                            ',' +
                            currentEvent.transform.y * 0.125 +
                            ') scale(' +
                            currentEvent.transform.k +
                            ')'
                    );
            })
            .scaleExtent([0.1, 1])
    )
    .on('dblclick.zoom', false)
    .on('wheel', function() {
        currentEvent.preventDefault();
    })
    .on('wheel', false);
```

I believe that I have to had some variable that is able to read the state of the transform translate, but how?

Comment: You need to handle all zooming through d3.zoom - this way d3.zoom is aware of the current zoom state. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55477585/7106086)'s answer should help, as the issue is ultimately the same.

Comment: @AndrewReid thank you for your answer.
I will read it carefully and try to implement it.
I shall update with the results.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer provided by @AndrewReid has helped me resolve my issue and the corrected version of the code is here:

```
function zoomFit() {
    let bounds = document.getElementById('svgContent').getBBox();
    let parent = document.getElementById('svgContent').parentElement;
    let fullWidth = parent.clientWidth,
        fullHeight = parent.clientHeight;
    let width = bounds.width,
        height = bounds.height;
    let midX = bounds.x + width / 2,
        midY = bounds.y + height / 2;
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) return; // nothing to fit
    let scale = 0.95 / Math.max(width / fullWidth, height / fullHeight);
    let translate = [
        fullWidth / 2 - scale * midX,
        fullHeight / 2 - scale * midY
    ];

    document
        .getElementById('svgContent')
        .setAttribute(
            'transform',
            'translate(' +
                translate[0] +
                ',' +
                translate[1] +
                ') scale(' +
                scale +
                ')'
        );

    // Create a zoom transform from d3.zoomIdentity
    var transform = zoomIdentity
        .scale(scale)
        .translate(-translate[0], -translate[1]);

    // Apply the zoom and trigger a zoom event:
    svg.call(zoom().transform, transform);
}

var zooming = zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 1])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [840, 740]])
    .on('zoom', zoomed);

svg.call(zooming);

function zoomed() {
    svg
        .attr('transform', currentEvent.transform)
        .on('dblclick.zoom', false)
        .on('wheel', function() {
            currentEvent.preventDefault();
        });
}
```

But another issue got in the way which is the panning function was lost.

I'll have to figure that one out and I'll update this answer has soon has the solutions is found.

Best regards,

Comment: I faced the same issue. After I added the `translateExtent` panning function was lost. Have you found a solution?