# Zoom/Pan should work from new position instead of JUMPING back to previous position

Tags: d3.js, zooming, pan

I want to translate 'g element' on the basis of the button click instead of mouse/finger. I successfully moved the 'g element' to the correct new position using 'translation' but when I zoom/pan from NEW position the 'g element' **JUMPS** back to its previous position and zooms/pans from that position. 
Please see the code of the function called **BtnClicked()**

Is there any way/function to set zoom/pan position to new LOCATION ? IN FACT in future I want to zoom/pan in such a way that GREEN RECTANGLE (the clicked element) comes to the center of the svg when it is clicked and when I use the mouse to zoom/pan it zoom/pan from GREEN RECTANGLE in the Center of the SVG.

Have been searching for quite some time in another project but unfortunately not successful.

```js
 // ONLY g will be zooming and panning inside the svg
        // Quite good understanding of zoom. It would help.

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);

        var svgRect = d3.select("svg")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("id", "rectsvg")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("fill", 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

        var g = d3.select("svg")
            .append("g");

        var r1 = d3.select("svg").select("g")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("id", "rec1")
            .attr("x", 150) // 150 means almost on the center of the svg
            .attr("y", 150) // as 500 is width and height and so upper left corner of this rect will be at 150,150
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100)
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("fill", 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

        var r2 = d3.select("svg").select("g")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("id", "rec2")
            .attr("x", 90) // 150 means almost on the center of the svg
            .attr("y", 50) // as 500 is width and height and so upper left corner of this rect will be at 150,150
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", 75)
            .attr("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("fill", 'green');


        var zoomListener = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.5, 3])  // NOTE: Zoom in will go 
            // maximum 1/2 of the original
            // and zoom out will go 
            // maximum 5 times. 
            .on("zoom", ZoomHandler);

        zoomListener(svg);

        function ZoomHandler() {

            // NOTE: Here if you change g with svg then
            // whole svg will be zoomed in and out
            // but IMHO it is better that svg and its rectange remain 
            // borderline rectange and things inside it i.e. g 
            // zoom in and zoom out. 
            g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);

        }

        function BtnClicked() {
            g.attr("transform", "translate(70,190)");
            // above code translates g to (70,190) point correctly
            // but when i zoom/pan from this point, instead of zooming/panning from this point it JUMPS back to the previous position and stars zooming/panning from there. :-(


        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Learning D3JS Zooming</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <button type="submit" onclick="BtnClicked()">BUTTON</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Which version of d3 used in this code?

Comment: "Is there any way/function to set zoom/pan position to new LOCATION ?" I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but if I do, the button click needs to call a zoom event so that the zoom knows the current zoom state, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55477585/7106086)

Comment: @AndrewReid. Thank you soooo very much. This is THE BEST and THE SIMPLEST explanation of zoom i have found after so many days of googling. Thanks again.