# d3.js v4 zoom via mouse wheel and programmatically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map with some clickable areas.
When a click on a location occurs my zoomto function is involved and the map zooms to the corresponding location.

but then the reference d3js is using (internal?) is out of sync, with the consequences that a mousewheel event on("zoom", zoomed) starts from a complete different angle.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5rzp6bxt/

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg");

var zoom=d3.zoom()
  .extent([[0, 0], [1200, 660]])
  .scaleExtent([1, 3])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
svg.call(zoom);
    
g = svg.append("g");

 g.append("circle")
   .attr("cx", document.body.clientWidth / 2)
   .attr("cy", document.body.clientHeight / 2)
   .attr("r", 20)
   .style("fill", "#B8DEE6").on("click", zoomto);
   
function zoomed(cords) {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);                
}


function zoomto(){
  
  g.transition()
           .duration(450).attr("transform", "translate(1.5, 1.5) scale(1.2)");
}
```

Comment: The zoom behaviour doesn't use the "transform" attribute of an element to determine what the current zoom state is, it only updates the zoom state when you trigger a zoom event. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55477585/7106086).

Answer (score 2):

thanks to the hint from Andrew Reid i was able to fix my issue.
here are my final goto function

```
function zoomto(x,y,k){
   var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
                  .translate(x,y)
                  .scale(k);

   svg.transition().duration(450).call(zoom.transform, transform);

}
```