# How to implement zoom to specific country and zoom in and out when using mouse scroll wheel together in datamap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, datamaps

I implemented the zoom when mouse scroll using datamaps inside done function as follows, successfully:

```
 done: function (datamap) {
        /* zoom on mouse scroll */
        datamap.svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));
        function redraw() {
          datamap.svg
            .selectAll("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
```

And also implemented the zoom to specific country successfully as well:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("choropleth_map");
    const { width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const canvasFactor = width / height;
    selectedCountry = isoCodeConverter[Country[0].code];
    const countryFeature = map.current.svg.selectAll(`.datamaps-subunit.${selectedCountry}`)["0"]["0"].__data__;
    if (countryFeature !== undefined) {
      const bounds = path.bounds(countryFeature); // get bounds of selected country
      bounds.s = bounds[0][1];
      bounds.n = bounds[1][1];
      bounds.w = bounds[0][0];
      bounds.e = bounds[1][0];
      bounds.height = Math.abs(bounds.n - bounds.s);
      bounds.width = Math.abs(bounds.e - bounds.w);
      newScale = 0.95 / Math.max(bounds.width / width, bounds.height / height);
      const factor = bounds.width / bounds.height;
      /* for maintaining width and height relative to the canvas size to keep the country in the middle */
      if (factor < 1.8) {
        bounds.w = bounds.w - Math.abs(bounds.height * canvasFactor - bounds.width) / 2;
      }
      if (factor > 1.8) {
        bounds.s = bounds.s - Math.abs(bounds.width / canvasFactor - bounds.height) / 2;
      }
      /* update the current map*/
      map.current.svg
        .selectAll("g")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", `scale(${newScale})translate(${-bounds.w},${-bounds.s})`);
    }
```

But there is a problem when i click on specific country(suppose the map gets zoomed to a zoom level about 6) and on using mouse scroll at that level, the map zooms out to the original scale i.e. 1 and not from the current scale i.e. 6. My approach to the problem is to save the current zoom and transform when the specific country is clicked and assign it to d3.event.scale if it's possible. Is there a better way? How do i get the current zoom level of the map when a specific country is clicked and how do i assign it to d3.event? when console logging d3.event inside the specific country function, it gives me null. I am new to datamaps as well so, i dont have a better understanding to solve it myself.

Comment: Take a look at [`zoom.event`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Zoom-Behavior.md#event) and use that to trigger your manual zooms.  The problem is you are not telling the zoom behavior you have altered the applied transform, it picks up where it left off. I've answered a few related questions from d3v4 through 7, but would have to take a closer look at v3 documentation (this was a substantial version change), though the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481420/7106086) you face is the same.

Comment: i made it working but i dont have a clear understanding of how it works. that documentation on zoom.event seems hard to understand since, my english is not so good. I will post the answer though. would you check it once, if possible?

Comment: Looks good and I'm not sure if I can provide any other insights - now you modify the zoom state of the map only through the zoom behavior itself, which is then implemented as a SVG transform on the map with the zoom event listener. Programmatic zooms independent of the zoom cause *a lot* of problems for people that wrongly expect their changing of a transform to also update or be observed by the zoom behavior. I do think the flow is a bit clearer in v4+ though, v3 was a bit more awkward when it came to zooms.

Answer (score 1):

I made it working though with guidance by Andrew Reid.Here is the code:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("choropleth_map");
    const { width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const canvasFactor = width / height;
    selectedCountry = isoCodeConverter[Country[0].code];
    const countryFeature = map.current.svg.selectAll(`.datamaps-subunit.${selectedCountry}`)["0"]["0"].__data__;
    if (countryFeature !== undefined) {
      const bounds = path.bounds(countryFeature); // get bounds of selected country
      bounds.s = bounds[0][1];
      bounds.n = bounds[1][1];
      bounds.w = bounds[0][0];
      bounds.e = bounds[1][0];
      bounds.height = Math.abs(bounds.n - bounds.s);
      bounds.width = Math.abs(bounds.e - bounds.w);
      newScale = 0.95 / Math.max(bounds.width / width, bounds.height / height);
      const x = (bounds.w + bounds.e) / 2;
      const y = (bounds.s + bounds.n) / 2;

      /* specify the current zoom and translation vector */
      zoom.scale(newScale);
      zoom.translate([width / 2 - newScale * x, height / 2 - newScale * y]);

      /* dispatches a zoom gesture to registered listeners */
      zoom.event(map.current.svg.selectAll("g").transition().duration(2000));
      map.current.svg.selectAll("g").call(zoom);
    }
```