# D3 zoom and pan zooming independently on mouse and programmatically

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Could some kind and clever D3 soul please put me out of my misery. I have the following example setup - https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-night-kpqc8t?file=/src/App.js. There are zoom buttons and the svg takes mouse events to initiate zoom. Problem is that the zoom triggered by the button is independent of that triggered by the button.

I believe this stackOverflow describes the problem and the solution - [D3.zoom jumps when using mouse wheel after programmatically zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477585/d3-zoom-jumps-when-using-mouse-wheel-after-programmatically-zoom) - I just cannot figure out the implementation for the life of me in the context I have.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I'm not entirely sure what the difference is, but somewhere along the line I must've been targeting the wrong element...

At the bottom of this article - https://www.d3indepth.com/zoom-and-pan/ - is an example codepen. Following the codepen to the letter resolved my issue.

Thanks,
Simon